# In C why can i just simply type numbers in programs but cant do so with other data types?

Tags: c

If i type only number 1 randomly in program without variable or function its fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
1;
    return 0;
}
```

But if i type for example letter a randomly its considered error?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
a;
    return 0;
}
```

Same with typing a boolean value like True.

Also what for example simply writing 1 like this does? When computer executes this program it prints Hello World to console and then when it comes to line with 1 what it does then? It simply stores 1 randomly somewhere without using it for anything? Since its not in variable or printed or anything?

Comment: Your first program example doesn't compile. Neither of them do. However if you had put `1;` that would be valid syntax and compile. The expression is evaluated and discarded. But `a;` cannot be evaluated because `a` has not been defined.

Comment: Compiling the first code with Clang yields a message “expected ';' after expression.” If you meant `1;`, then fix the code, and the reason it is accepted is that it forms a C *expression-statement*, which is the same as `x = y+3;` (a statement that is an expression followed by `;`, where `x = y+3` is an *assignment-expression*) or as `printf("Hello World");`, where `printf("Hello World")` is a *postfix-expression*. `true;` also forms an *expression-statement*, if `<stdbool.h>` has been included. `a;` gets an error because `a` is not declared.

Comment: All expression statements discard the final value of the expression. They are used for their side effects, in which one or more things inside the expression cause effects such as storing a value in an object (as in `x = 3`) or writing output (`printf("Hello, world.\n")`).

Comment: You are making an assumption that the expression ends up in the program at all. The compiler will most likely ignore it and leave it out. But similarly, ask yourself what happens to the number `11` that is returned by the `printf` statement.

Comment: @ Eric Postpischil Could you explain to me why is it an expression if it number. Like why would number 1 be evaluated to determine its value when its obviously value of 1. Then by that logic literally everything is expression

Comment: @20centuryboy yes [almost everything is an expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions), including `a`. If you've declared it first then `int a; a;` would compile without any errors although there'll an uninitialized warning. Basically an expression can be an operand on its own or multiple expressions combined together with an operator. Read the standard and see the [grammar for expressions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#A.1.2.1) and you'll see `identifier`, `constant` or `string-literal` are expressions

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question concerning the form of an expression. Yes, unfortunately the OP didn't copy his test program correctly, and the first example didn't compile until it was edited, but this, and the issue that was confusing the OP, would have been obvious to anyone proficient in C. I really wish people didn't reflexively hit the 'close' button.

Comment: @EML It's nice to see that SO's processes work (most of the time), this question is open again for good answers. ;-)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Then why does this code result in error could you explain please.  void comparexy (int x,int y) { if (x>y) {printf("X is bigger");} else if (x<y) {printf("x is smaller");} else {printf("They are equal");} } int printinfunction() { int x=2; return x; } int main() { comparexy (printinfunction,1); } It wont accept printinfunction as argument even though it returns an int

Comment: @20centuryboy edit the question and include that in the question itself. It's unreadable and no one will read it in comments

Answer (score 6):

It may not be obvious at first, but most of the lines in a C program are *expression statements*.  An expression statement consists of an expression that computes some value, and (usually) also does something useful along the way.  For example, the statement

```
a = b + c;
```

evaluates an ordinary expression, and since the expression includes the assignment operator `=` to assign a result to the variable `a`, this expression does something useful — after it executes, `a` has a new value.

Another example is

```
printf("Hello, world!\n");
```

In this expression statement, the expression consists of a call to the function `printf`.  Like many functions, `printf` returns a value, but in this expression, nothing is being done with that value, so it is discarded.  But, since the `printf` function itself did something interesting along the way, this statement does something useful, too.

But here's another expression statement:

```
2 + 3;
```

This statement evaluates an expression, but it ends up being not at all interesting.  Although a value is computed, it's not assigned to anything.  And there are no function calls that might do anything interesting.

And then your example

```
1;
```

is an even more minimal example of the same sort of thing.  This is an expression statement consisting of the single constant `1`.  So when we evaluate this expression, we get the value 1.  But, again, since there are no assignment operators or function calls or other side effects, this is not a useful or an interesting expression statement — but it *is* a syntactically valid expression statement.

Finally, your other question concerned the expression statement

```
a;
```

This, also, is a superficially valid expression statement, that would take the value of the variable `a`, and then do nothing with it.  The only problem here is that the variable `a` has not been declared, so this expression isn't valid, after all.

These do-nothing expression statements aren't illegal, but since they don't do anything interesting, you wouldn't want them in your programs; they're probably a mistake.  So a good compiler will warn about them: one compiler I tried said "warning: expression result unused".

---

In a comment you asked, "Why would number 1 be evaluated to determine its value when it's obviously value of 1. Then by that logic literally everything is an expression."  That's true: Just about everything *is* an expression.

To see why, we have to think a little bit about the *grammar* that describes the syntax of the C language.  Let's say we want to assign a value to a variable.  The syntax for that is

> *variable* `=` *expression*

On the left we have a variable name, and on the right we have an expression.  The expression can be just about anything, so we can have

```
a = b + c;
```

or

```
x = sqrt(y);
```

or

```
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

or even just

```
a = 1;
```

But if we can say `a = 1;` to assign the value 1 to `a`, that means that the constant `1`, all by itself, has to be an expression!  It's a dirt-simple expression, that we hardly have to "evaluate" because it's already a value, but it's an expression all the same.

Now, you might be saying "Okay, I get it, `1` is an expression, but why can you put it alone on a line?" And the answer is, when you get down to it, *every* expression statement is an "expression alone on a line."  If you have the very ordinary line

```
printf("Hello, world!\n");
```

that's an expression alone on a line.  And it turns out that the assignment operator `=` is basically just another operator, so the assignment expression `a = b + c` is just another expression.  It's rare, but you can say things like

```
a = (b = 4) + (c = 5);
```

which contain assignments embedded in larger expressions.  But since assignment is an expression, that means that the statement

```
a = b + c;
```

is, also, "an expression alone on a line".

So you can think of this as a sort of a law of unintended consequences.  Given the way expressions and expression statements are defined in C, the useless-looking statement

```
1;
```

*has* to be legal — although again, since it's useless, a good compiler will warn you about it.

Comment: A nice example of how what is apparently a stupid question can lead to useful insights. I regularly use a language where the concept of expression statements was never thought through, and asignment isn't an operator, and the language (Verilog) is basically broken.

Comment: Thank you can please then explain to me regarding return value why does this code throw an error 
void comparexy (int x,int y)
{ 
    
    if (x>y)
    {printf("X is bigger");}
    
    else if (x<y)
    {printf("x is smaller");}
        
    else {printf("They are equal");}
    }
    
    int printinfunction() {
        int x=2;
        return x;
    }
int main()
{
    comparexy (printinfunction,1);
    
}



It wont accept printinfunction as argument even though it returns an int

Comment: @20centuryboy: In your previous comment, you probably need to change the line `comparexy (printinfunction,1);` to `comparexy( printinfunction(), 1 );`, i.e. you must add `()` for a function call. Otherwise, you are passing a pointer to the function `printinfunction`, which is not an `int`. You can see your fixed code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/sbP7Mhvj5).